# How does Apple Store's Input box prevent user clicking on the search box taken to be clicking on the prompting phrase?

Tags: html, css

I can use a different way to put to prompt phrase in an input box, but I like the way that the prompt phrase stays even when the cursor is blinking, so this is how it is like:

The website is http://store.apple.com/us

At the **TOP-RIGHT** corner of the page, there is a search box, with a prompt phrase which is a `<span>`, which is `position: absolute` in the container.

Also in the container is the `<input>` element, with `position: static`

So the prompt `span` is imposed on top of the `input`, to have the current effect.

But what I don't understand is, when the user clicks on the prompt phrase `span`, won't the clicking be on the `<span>`?  So the `<input>` will not get the focus, and there will be no cursor blinking, user cannot type into the box.  How is that overcome?

**I don't think using Javascript to handle this is a good way**, because what if the user disabled Javascript?  The Apple Store's website also has the effect that with Javascript disabled, if clicking on the prompt phrase span, the prompt phrase span will disappear -- how is that done?  I am guessing it is done by some CSS `:focus` pseudo class or some other ways.

This is a JSFiddle if you want to play with it:  http://jsfiddle.net/hndWc/6/

**Update:** Please don't use Javascript make the input have focus, just like Apple Store with Javascript disabled, it can still make the input have focus.

Comment: It's not too difficult. Click on the span will expand the field and focus on the input.

Comment: @JohnP try it in the JSFiddle... you don't need to expand the field.  Just make it focused, and as I said: No Javascript.  Try the Apple Store site with Javascript disabled and click on the prompt phrase -- the input element still get focused.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is being used. If you disable JavaScript, then you no longer get the initial text.

The way they have it done is, they wrap the span tag with the label tag. Initial text is inside the span tag. On keyuyp, the label tag get hidden so span tag is no longer showing since it's parent is hidden. If you disable JavaScript then you get no label or span tag by default which means no initial text since we can no longer use keyup to hide it.

**UPDATE**

They use the :focsed CSS selector to achieve background change when input is focused. Check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: but if you disable Javascript, you click on the prompt phrase, and the input field still gets focus.  Try the JSFiddle in the original question.  Apple can do it without Javascript so when user clicks on prompt phrase, the input element gets focus.  How would you do it in the JSFiddle, with Javascript disabled like Apple?

Comment: I tried this directly at apply website. The focus you are getting is a background change done via CSS when js is disabled

Comment: Also there is no prompt phrase if you disable javascript. After disabling javascript make sure you refresh the page to see changes.

Comment: There is an "Initial prompt phrase" -- there isn't a "Staying prompt phrase"... so how does the "initial prompt phrase" not block the user's click on the input element?

Comment: I checked again. No phrase when javascript is disabled.

Comment: @動靜能量 the initial prompt phrase is HTML5. See the link in my answer

Comment: In that case it's not cross browser. Because in Firefox if you disable javaScript then you get not phrase.

Comment: They use CSS :focus selector achieve focus background change. See attached screenshot. It's very straight forward,  No phrase when JS is disabled. If you see phrase in some browsers, then it's a browser things and not cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle just a bit to show a rough example : http://jsfiddle.net/hndWc/8/

```
$('#prompt-text').click(function(){
    $('#prompt-text').hide();  
    $('#input-element').focus();
});
```

This is not complete of course. I'd put in some code to see whether the input or the span has focus so that we can capture the keyboard navigation stuff as well. Not just the click.

**EDIT**

Apple may not be layering functionality. Having a closer look, they are using HTML5. They are using the `placeholder` attribute of input elements

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: nice try, except (1) don't use Javascript to do it, just like the Apple Store site with Javascript disabled.  (2) don't hide the `#prompt-text` when prompt phrase is clicked on, that is the reason I would do it this way instead of just having input element and "put words in" to act as a prompt

Comment: they are using HTML 5 to do it?  Then it shouldn't work on IE 8, but it is... are they switching HTML and CSS...?  will look some more

Comment: Yep, HTML5 placeholder is the key here.